# Solution Deployed Successfully but Web parts not available

Tags: 2010, powershell, solution-package

I'm running into a deployment problem in my sharepoint 2010 environment.  I built a small 'Hello World' type web part in visual studio 2010 and then deployed to my development environment via visual studio.  Everything works fine so I moved the .wsp file to my production server and attempted to deploy via powershell using the add-spsolution and install-spsolution commands.

Everything appears to work fine, there were no errors, and I've checked in Central admin and the solutions are listed as deployed under Central Administration -> Solution management.  Running get-spsolution tells me the same thing, and I've confirmed that the safe control entry was added to the web.config file for the site and it appears (to me anyway) to be listed correctly in the assembly folder for windows.

But for whatever reason, I cannot see it when I try to add a webpart to a page or when I view the web part gallery list under Site Settings?

I've tried adding the .webpart file directly from my project to the gallery but that then creates the following error message when I try to add it to the page afterwards:

$Resources:core,ImportErrorMessage;

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: did you check if it is on the web part gallery?

Comment: Yes, when I run the commands from powershell even thought it appears successful it does not appear in the webpart gallery, and if I try to add the .webpart file myself it gets added, but then if I try to add it to a page afterwards I get the error message I listed above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume your solution has a Feature, in which case you most likely need to activate it on the site collection itself via the [Enable-SPFeature](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607803.aspx) powershell command

Comment: You are correct, I forgot about that step which visual studio takes care of for me when I deploy in my test environment

Answer (score 0):

$Ressources is not related to any localization ressources? Are you in a multinlingual farm? the farm and the developpement server are in the same language? Did you check the ressources folder in 14/ressources and in the iis webapp App_GlobalResources, that contains the same number of files?